# Safari having trouble in running animation with mp3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an animation project in which all the animation is applied through jQuery and JavaScript, it also contain some audio MP3 clips throughout the project.... Well.. its all functioning properly in all the browsers i.e. Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera etc but the browser which trouble me is safari... None of my MP3s are working on Safari. I am calling my function like this:

```
function treeover() {
    if (document.getElementById('hvalue').value == "zk") {
        playmusic1('voices/home/treehouse.mp3');
    }
}
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting on the console of safari ?

Comment: There is no error shown in safari console box.

Comment: try if it is actually entering inside `if` statement ?
 `if (document.getElementById('hvalue').value == "zk") { console.log("inside if");        playmusic1('voices/home/treehouse.mp3');
    }`

Comment: it is entering, thats y its working on other browsers.. its not working only on Safari

Comment: can u guess me any script or something to apply so that the mp3 could work on safari.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to give a `type` attribute to audio

**Eg:**

```
<source  src="voices/home/treehouse.mp3" type="audio/mp3"  />
```

If the above is not working ,an effective solution would be to convert your mp3 to mp4 and that would make it work across all the browsers

Refer to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/18320431#18320431) thread on the Apple discussion forum

Answer (score 0):

call  audioDOM.play() method  inside canplaythrough event listener.